# Writing an algorithm for insertion sort in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement insertion sort in Java. I think something isn't quite right with my code.

```
public int[] sort(int[] unsorted) {
    int i, j, v;
    for (i = 1; i < unsorted.length - 1; i++) {
        v = unsorted[i];
        j = i;

        while (unsorted[j-1] > v && j >= 1) {
            unsorted[j] = unsorted[j -1];
            j--;
        }
        unsorted[j] = v;
    }
    return unsorted;
}
```

I get an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** for my while loop `([j-1])`. But how can I rewrite the code so it actually works?

Comment: HINT: What happens in your `while` statement condition when `j` has just been decremented down to zero?  You need to check first if the value of `j` is "safe" **before** accessing `unsorted[j-1]`.

Comment: as a suggestion, do not call it `unsorted`. Returning `unsorted` from a method called `sort` is misleading, at least. Just `source`, or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For index `i`, you can simply start the index `j` from `i-1`. And in the while loop, always put the index validity check first, before accessing data from that index. The following code solves your problem:

```
public int[] sort(int[] unsorted) {
    int i, j, v;
    for (i = 1; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        v = unsorted[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && unsorted[j] > v) {
            unsorted[j + 1] = unsorted[j];
            j--;
        }
        unsorted[j + 1] = v;
    }
    return unsorted;
}
```

Comment: it does, no doubts ; )

Comment: I agree with you! :) Old habit to say like this.

Comment: I do it, too. But better to show security. You solved it, 100%.